# Dependency Injection the right way in Php - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, laravel-5.5, lumen-5.4

I have a log class as below and I would like to inject below class to my controller and make a log:

## Log.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

use DB;


class Log {

    private $tableName;
    private $tableId;
    private $tableIdVal;
    private $step;
    private $status;
    private $error;

    public function __construct($logTableName, $logTableId, $logTableIdVal, $step, $status, $error = null) {

        $this->tableName = $logTableName;
        $this->tableId   = $logTableId;
        $this->tableIdVal= $logTableIdVal;
        $this->step      = $step;
        $this->status    = $status;
        $this->error     = $error;

    }

    protected function create() {

        DB::table($this->tableName)->insert(
            [
                $this->tableId  =>  $this->tableIdVal,
                'step'          =>  $this->step,
                'error'         =>  $this->error,
                'status'        =>  $this->status
            ]
        );
    }

}
```

## Testcontroller.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Helpers\{Load, Log};
use App\Models\{Post, Raw, RawDetail};

use DB;

class DetailsController extends Controller
{
    private $file;
    private $log;

    public function __construct($record, Log $logger) {

        $this->file = $record;
        $this->log  = $logger;
    }

public function process() {

        //make a log (is this correct?) I think $this->log will find a log method in this file, which does not exist.
        //I want to simple make a call to the constructor and then call create method on it.
        $this->log('raw_logs', 'raw_id', $this->file->id, Raw::STEP_1, Raw::STATUS_1);
```

If I am using dependency injection how should I do the above?

I can do it like below:

```
$log = new Log($all-params-here);
$log->create();
```

But I want to avoid using new.

What I want to do.

```
$this->log($parameters)->create();
```

Comment: Why not setting the arguments in the `create()` method? `create(($logTableName, ...)` then you can do `$this->log->create($a, $b, ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can do like @HtmHell said in the comment ex: `$this->log->create(parameters);`
2. You create method chaining ex: `$this->log->setData($parameters)->create();`